# Apache tomcat server for yum repo

Tags: linux, tomcat, yum, repository, update

I have a system that currently has apache tomcat on it (RHEL 6.5). I also want to make a yum update repo on this system for other systems on the network (also RHEL 6.5). I know I can use the apache http server to accomplish this and since I am new to servers, I am wondering if tomcat can also be used for this as well?

Comment: It's all a bunch of static files. Why on earth would you need tomcat?

Comment: @MichaelHampton like I said, I already have tomcat and I also have limited space on the computer so if I can deploy updates using tomcat that would be much better then having to waste space installing apache http if tomcat can do the same task.